# Gzip and subprocess' stdout in python

Tags: python, gzip, subprocess

I'm using python 2.6.4 and discovered that I can't use gzip with subprocess the way I might hope.  This illustrates the problem:

```
May 17 18:05:36> python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Mar 10 2010, 14:41:19)
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import gzip
>>> import subprocess
>>> fh = gzip.open("tmp","wb")
>>> subprocess.Popen("echo HI", shell=True, stdout=fh).wait()
0
>>> fh.close()
>>>
[2]+  Stopped                 python
May 17 18:17:49> file tmp
tmp: data
May 17 18:17:53> less tmp
"tmp" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
May 17 18:17:58> zcat tmp

zcat: tmp: not in gzip format
```

Here's what it looks like inside less

```
HI
^_<8B>^H^Hh<C0><F1>K^B<FF>tmp^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

which looks like it put in the stdout as text and then put in an empty gzip file.  Indeed, if I remove the "Hi\n", then I get this:

```
May 17 18:22:34> file tmp
tmp: gzip compressed data, was "tmp", last modified: Mon May 17 18:17:12 2010, max compression
```

What is going on here?

**UPDATE:**
This earlier question is asking the same thing: [Can I use an opened gzip file with Popen in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732811/can-i-use-an-opened-gzip-file-with-popen-in-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use file-likes with `subprocess`, only real files. The `fileno()` method of `GzipFile` returns the FD of the underlying file, so that's what the echo redirects to. The GzipFile then closes, writing an empty gzip file.

Comment: I guess I am piping through gzip then.

Answer (score 8):

just pipe that sucker

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
GZ = Popen("gzip > outfile.gz",stdin=PIPE,shell=True)
P = Popen("echo HI",stdout=GZ.stdin,shell=True)
# these next three must be in order
P.wait()
GZ.stdin.close()
GZ.wait()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure why this isn't working (perhaps the output redirection is not calling python's write, which is what gzip works with?) but this works:

```
>>> fh.write(subprocess.Popen("echo Hi", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read())
```

Comment: For a really big file, this may cause memory issues

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to use `subprocess` to write to the `gzip.GzipFile`. Instead,  write to it like any other file-like object. The result is automagically gzipped!

```
import gzip
with gzip.open("tmp.gz", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write('echo HI')
```